# onReceive method of BroadcastReceiver is not getting called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I know there are many SO posts related to this topic but none is working here.

I am doing `sendBroadcast` call from the class **UserEntry.java:** ---

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(DeviceScanActivity.ACTION_DISCONNECTED);
intent.putExtra(DeviceScanActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME, bdDevice.getName());
intent.putExtra(DeviceScanActivity.EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS,  bdDevice.getAddress());
getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

I have defined my broadcast receiver in class **DeviceScanActivity.java:** as ---

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mUpdateReceiver = 
new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            device_name = intent.getExtras().getString(DeviceScanActivity.
            EXTRAS_DEVICE_NAME);
            device_address = intent.getExtras().getString(DeviceScanActivity.
            EXTRAS_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
            if (ACTION_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mConnected = "Connected";
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            } else if (ACTION_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mConnected = "Disconnected";
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            } else if (ACTION_CONNECTING.equals(action)) {
                mConnected = "Connecting";
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
            else
            {
                mConnected = "";
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }
    };

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        registerReceiver(mUpdateReceiver, makeUpdateIntentFilter());
}

 @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mUpdateReceiver);
}
```

So, user clicks connect button and `sendBroadcast` is called from class `UserEntry` then user switch to class `DeviceScanActivity` and still `onReceive` is never get called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are registering the `BroadcastReceiver` in DeviceScanActivity.java which means it won't be registered until DeviceScanActivity is active.

In other words the broadcast will simply get lost because there isn't a receiver available to receive the broadcast.

Comment: yes but I want to change my UI of `DeviceScanActivity.java` so when user comes to this class, it should be registered and the `onReceive` should get called ? My logic flow is from `UserEntry => DeviceScanActivity`. So if socket is connected then I am sending broadcast from UserEntry then whenever user comes to DeviceScanActivity then the UI should show the connected status.

Comment: Why don't you just use SharedPreferences to hold a 'flag' of some sort? Perhaps a `boolean` to say whether it's connected or not. There's no point in sending a broadcast if there isn't an active receiver.

Comment: Until your activity not register the receiver ... the call will not come to the onReceive() ... So if you want to start the activity with some ui change then need to register the receiver in the menifext file and implement a new class for this register from there you will got the call always and then u can start the activity...

Comment: I thought of `SharedPreferences` approach and did that also. Then I realized that I also need connected device MAC address to be passed to DeviceScanActivity class. So there will be more flags to be set to  `SharedPreferences`. And I approached to the idea of `BroadcastReceiver`. Seemed best to me. Let's see.

Comment: What difference is there between putting device name and address into `Intent` extras and simply storing them using `SharedPreferences`? I don't understand your logic.

Comment: Thanks I did using `SharedPreferences`. The difference was nothing, just a thought that of not having too many flags as it already has in the app for various other purposes. But your point is right.